# Angular $http get

Tags: ajax, angularjs

I want to make an ajax call in angularJS, JSON is loading but the data is not populating.

```
    demoApp.controller('MainController', function($scope, GetData) {

        $scope.data = null;
        GetData.getDoctors(function(dataResponse) {
            $scope.data = dataResponse;
        });

    });


    demoApp.factory('GetData', function($http) {

        var doctors = [];
        this.getDoctors = function(callBack) {
            $http({

                method: 'GET',
                url: 'json/location.json'
            }).
            success(function(data) {
                callBack(data);
            }).
            error(function(data) {
                alert("Error");
            });

        }
    });
```

Even the Json file is not loading ..what is the error in the code?

Comment: In your view, are you reading $scope.doctors or $scope.data?

Comment: sorry there was a mistake ,edited it, i am reading $scope.data which is obvious now.

Comment: If you hit `http://yourdomain/json/location.json` directly with your browser, do you see the expected data?

Comment: Yes i am able to see the JSON..

Comment: Could you try the following syntax: http://codepad.org/ohWEiNsI?

Comment: no buddy! !not working

Comment: The code mentioned by @sp00m should work!!

Comment: But i tried twice now, it is not working.....will i have to explicitly how the callback function passed in parameter? If yes can you also please tell me how to do it .

Answer (score 0):

Angular factory should return something.

Try

```
demoApp.factory('GetData', function($http) {
    var methods = {};

    methods.getDoctors = function(callBack) {
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'json/location.json'
        }).
        success(function(data) {
            callBack(data);
        }).
        error(function(data) {
            alert("Error");
        });
    };

    return methods;
});
```